# TensorFlow v1.10+: get_checkpoint_state what is the expected value for latest_filename for Estimator API to specify a particular checkpoint

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

The function [`tf.train.get_checkpoint_state`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/3699977134badccb7032fa6921d70e01ba8fdf7d/tensorflow/python/training/checkpoint_management.py#L246) (line 246) has the following function signature (as defined in the file [checkpoint_management](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/3699977134badccb7032fa6921d70e01ba8fdf7d/tensorflow/python/training/checkpoint_management.py))

```py
def get_checkpoint_state(checkpoint_dir, latest_filename=None):
  """Returns CheckpointState proto from the "checkpoint" file.
  If the "checkpoint" file contains a valid CheckpointState
  proto, returns it.
  Args:
    checkpoint_dir: The directory of checkpoints.
    latest_filename: Optional name of the checkpoint file.  Default to
      'checkpoint'.
  Returns:
    A CheckpointState if the state was available, None
    otherwise.
  Raises:
    ValueError: if the checkpoint read doesn't have model_checkpoint_path set.
  """
```

To me it is not very clear what exactly `latest_filename` is expecting, or how I can get a specific checkpoint, rather than the latest one (if several checkpoints are in the same directory)

The second line of the above function is:

```py
coord_checkpoint_filename = _GetCheckpointFilename(checkpoint_dir,
                                                     latest_filename)
```

which is defined on [line 43](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/3699977134badccb7032fa6921d70e01ba8fdf7d/tensorflow/python/training/checkpoint_management.py#L43) as:

```py
def _GetCheckpointFilename(save_dir, latest_filename):
  """Returns a filename for storing the CheckpointState.
  Args:
    save_dir: The directory for saving and restoring checkpoints.
    latest_filename: Name of the file in 'save_dir' that is used
      to store the CheckpointState.
  Returns:
    The path of the file that contains the CheckpointState proto.
  """
  if latest_filename is None:
    latest_filename = "checkpoint"
  return os.path.join(save_dir, latest_filename)
```

So this narrows down the type to a string.

The `tf.estimator.Estimator` API saves checkpoints in the form of:

```
model.ckpt-<#####>.index
model.ckpt-<#####>.meta
model.ckpt-<#####>.data-<#####>-of-<#####>
```

So if I am using these checkpoints, if I want to specify *which* checkpoint, do I call:

```py
tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(estimator_model_dir, latest_filename="model.ckpt-<#####>")
```

I have tried:

```py
CHECKPOINT_DIR = "path/to/checkpoints"
ckpt_num = "model.ckpt-#####"

file = ckpt_num
# file = ckpt_num + 'data-00000-of-00001'
# file = ckpt_num + 'index'
# file = ckpt_num + 'meta'

checkpoint = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(CHECKPOINT_DIR, file)
checkpoint.model_checkpoint_path
```

all of which throw errors e.g.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa1 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Leaving out the file, gives me the latest checkpoint, which may not be the one I want...

Comment: Looking at [line 271](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/3699977134badccb7032fa6921d70e01ba8fdf7d/tensorflow/python/training/checkpoint_management.py#L271) in the file, it seems it expects the exact file name in the directory, so I would guess it's `model.ckpt-<#####>.data-<#####>-of-<#####>`

Comment: @Zionsof just updated to give more context, that throws `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa1 in position 0: invalid start byte`

Comment: Just to make sure, do you actually have a `checkpoint` file in the directory? In what way does its content differ from a previous checkpoint `model.ckpt-#####` file?

Comment: Yes, I have several where `#####` is based on the criteria I setup in my Estimator to dump out checkpoints. e.g. `#####` might be `0`, `8341`, `16801`, etc and not specifying the `latest_filename` works without error, but it gives me always the _last_ checkpoint, and I rather specify which to use (e.g. the last may not be the _best_)

Comment: Yes, but what about the content? Can you see any major difference in the content of the files?

Comment: @Zionsof I am not sure what you mean. These are checkpoints of the model. The files are not equivalent and correspond to a model state with different accuracy etc. So being able to specify `get_checkpoint_state` from a __specific__ checkpoint is important. As for opening the file and "reading" it, well the encoded file I can not, and the data file is too large for me to want to use a text editor to inspect. `head <file>` does show difference

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195625/discussion-between-zionsof-and-sumneuron).